# QT Remote debug. Stepping into shared library

Tags: qt, debugging, gdb, shared-libraries, cross-compiling

I've crosscompiled qt using qtcreator. Debug works good, but when I try to step in (F11) a function defined in an external shared library (of mine), I see gdb hanging and finally fail with the following error:

> 115^error,msg="Reply contains invalid hex digit 116" 
>  COOKIE FOR TOKEN 115 ALREADY EATEN (InferiorStopOk). TWO RESPONSES FOR ONE COMMAND? 
>  Executable failed: Reply contains invalid hex digit 116

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the problem is related to the use of "step-in" (F11) function.

Inexplicably, you can avoid this message toggling a breakpoint in the library and simply using play function (F5), in order to debug your library.

Thanks anyway for your response. I've done a lot of tests before focusing the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

It could be:

1. A general gdb bug unrelated to the communications protocol,
2. A gdb bug in its gdb communications protocol implementation,
3. A Qt Creator bug in the gdb communications protocol implementation.

Since it is a bug in any case, you're after good information to put into the bug report. Examine Qt Creator's debugger log to see exactly when it happens. You can then try to reproduce the same command stream manually, from gdb's command line. If you succeed, then #1 is unlikely. You could use another IDE (say Eclipse) to differentiate between #2 and #3, but remember that the other IDE is unlikely to issue the same commands that Qt Creator would issue.

The only sure way of debugging it is interposing a small program between Qt Creator and gdb, dumping the commands that Qt creator has sent, then replaying them without Qt Creator. You then need to parse the responses and ascertain whether they are valid. If they are, then neither #1 nor #2 holds and it's very likely a Qt Creator bug, #3.

Answer (score 0):

The 'error,msg=' is generated by GDB in response to a GDBserver message. Qt Creator's communication with GDB is not involved. So this is a mis-communication between GDB and GDBserver.

Is that a proper GDBserver, and a GDB for that target architecture?

Btw, one does not need a program to intercept what Qt Creator send to GDB, it's all listed in the left pane of the debugger log.